# How to get a PowerBi widget to display 0 instead of blank after filtering?

Tags: powerbi

I have a single card widget on my dashboard that supposed to be showing a teams Work in Progress (WIP). This card is counting the work items in a table and filtering them by team and status.

My problem is that when a team has no work items in a "working" status, the card displays Blank instead of 0.

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 0):

Add + 0 to the end of your measure.

Comment: I'm not using a measure though.  I'm using the filter pane. Is there a way to do this without having to create a measure?

When I publish the dashboard I want the end user to be able to use this filter pane to display the data they need. Using a measure would prevent this.

Comment: There is no other way. Measures are critical if you want to get the most from PowerBI so this is a good opportunity to begin learning about them.

Comment: @JeremyJed It is not possible using filter pane. I tested it. David is right. I think You should accept his answer.